# NodeJS: How to fix "cannot find module 'node-windows' while compiling with pkg

Tags: node.js

While working on a particular project, I discovered I could compile my console applications with the pkg module. After installing it, I tested it out on my main app and it worked. When I tried it on "Service.js" (a service installer in the project) I got the warning (despite the fact that I have node-windows in the node_modules folder)

```
    Warning Cannot find module 'node-windows' from 'C:\Users\Uchenna\Documents\NodeJS\Ghost'
```

C:\Users\Uchenna\Documents\NodeJS\Ghost\Service.js

I tried ignoring it and went ahead to run "Service.exe --install"then I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'node-windows'
1) If you want to compile the package/file into executable, please pay attention to compilation warnings and specify a literal in 'require' call. 2) If you don't want to compile the package/file into executable and want to 'require' it from filesystem (likely plugin), specify an absolute path in 'require' call using process.cwd() or process.execPath.
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:592:15)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1280:46)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:518:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:648:17)
    at Module.require (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1159:31)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\Ghost\Service.js:0:0)
    at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1254:22)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:711:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:32)
```

Here's the code in the Service.js file

```
const Service = require("node-windows").Service;

class ServiceInstaller
{
    constructor () {
        var logServerService = new Service({
            name: "Log Server Service",
            description: "Listens for data to log",
            script: "./DataLoggerServer.exe"
        });

        var mainService = new Service({
            name: "Main Application Service",
            description: "Logs data (or errors) to the Log Server Service",
            script: "./Ghost.exe"
        });
    }

    installServices () {
        logServerService.install();
        mainService.install();

        logServerService.on("install", function () {
            logServerService.start();
            console.log("Successfully installed the 'Log Server' service\n");
        });

        mainService.on("install", function () {
            mainService.start();
            console.log("Successfully installed the main service\n");
        });
    }

    uninstallServices () {
        logServerService.uninstall();
        mainService.uninstall();

        logServerService.on("install", function () {
            logServerService.start();
            console.log("Successfully uninstalled the 'Log Server' service\n");
        });

        mainService.on("install", function () {
            mainService.start();
            console.log("Successfully uninstalled the main service\n");
        });
    }
}

var installer = new ServiceInstaller();

if (process.argv[2] == "install") {
    installer.installServices();
}
else if (process.argv[2] == "uninstall") {
    installer.uninstallServices();
}
else {
    console.log("Not running...\n");
}
```

Comment: Damn... I'm running into this too. It seems it may not be possible to package node-windows into an installable electron application?

Comment: I think so too. I just wish someone has a fix for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certain packages when build using pkg is showing this error.

For me it was bcrypt.

Look into the error message and find out which executable the error message is referring to. Then copy that executable from node_modules folder (mostly it will be from this folder), and paste it along side the executable.

This resolved the issue for me

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'll try that right away

Comment: If you get it correct upvote my answer, so that others who have similar issue can solve theirs

Comment: It worked. I tried testing out a few things as well. It turns out that is our use "npm install --save <module>" in the project you're working in the binary issues will also be resolved.

Comment: I didn't understand can you explain it once again?

Comment: I tried using "npm install --save <module>" in the project directory and that worked too.